# Can I move the test function into the inner commutators and skip the operator on the outside?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, physics, quantum-mechanics

Consider:

$$\frac{1}{2m}(\hat p (\hat p \hat x-\hat x \hat p) + (\hat p \hat x-\hat x \hat p) \hat p)f,$$
where $\hat p=$ momentum operator and $\hat x=$ position operator.

Can I do the following?

$$\frac{1}{2m}(\hat p (\hat p \hat x(f)-\hat x \hat p(f)) + (\hat p \hat x(f)-\hat x \hat p(f)) \hat p)$$

In case you're interested, I'm trying to figure out what $\frac{1}{2m}[\hat p^2,\hat x]$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity
\begin{align}
[\hat x, \hat p] = i\hbar\delta
\end{align}
we see that
\begin{align}
[\hat p^2, \hat x] =&\ \hat p^2\hat x-\hat x \hat p^2 =\hat p(\hat x\hat p-i\hbar \delta) - (\hat p \hat x+i\hbar\delta)\hat p\\
=&\ \hat p \hat x\hat p-i\hbar\hat p -\hat p \hat x \hat p -i\hbar\hat p = -2i\hbar p. 
\end{align}

Moreover, if you want to use test functions, then it will go as follows
\begin{align}
[p^2, x] \varphi =&\ p[p(x(\varphi))]-x[p(p(\varphi))] \\
=&\ p[x(p(\varphi))-i\hbar\varphi]-p[x(p(\varphi))]-i\hbar p[\varphi]\\
=&\  -2i\hbar p[\varphi].
\end{align}

Additional: To help you understand the process more, let us write it more explicitly as follows
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{d^2}{dx^2}, x\right]f(x)=& \left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x- x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)f(x)\\
=&\  \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[xf(x)]- x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x).
\end{align}

Comment: I know that's the final answer, but my **main** question was whether or not I am allowed to distribute the test function $f$ in the manner I have shown above.

Comment: Think everything in terms of matrices. Basically, you have $[A(AB-BA)+A(BA-AB)]v$... something similar.